# Redirect a page in to a struts action action with parameters

Tags: jakarta-ee, struts

How can I redirect a page using a subpath, to an struts 1 action with parameters?

Example: myserver.com/subpath redirect ti myserver.com/myaction.do?method=init

Comment: Are you using a web server? Easy to do with e.g. Apache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this.
Create index.jsp file in subpath directory with this short code.

```
<jsp:forward page="myserver.com/myaction.do">
  <jsp:param name="method" value="init"/> 
</jsp:forward>
```

or

```
<% response.sendRedirect("myserver.com/myaction.do?method=init"); %>
```